# Why is copy constructor called rather than move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(const A& a) noexcept { cout << "copy constructor" << endl; }
    A& operator=(const A& a) noexcept { cout << "copy assignment operator" << endl; }
    A(A&& a) noexcept { cout << "move constructor" << endl; }
    A& operator=(A&& a) noexcept { cout << "move assignment operator" << endl; }
    A() { cout << "default constructor" << endl; }
};

vector<A> aList;

void AddData(const A&& a)
{
    aList.push_back(std::move(a));
}

int main()
{
    AddData(A());
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `default constructor copy constructor`. please tell me is the rvalue reference `push_back(T&&)`called? And when is copy constructor called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is with the `a` parameter in `AddData()`:

```
void AddData(const A&& a) // <-- const reference!!!
{
    aList.push_back(std::move(a)); // selects push_back(const A&)
}
```

The `a` parameter above is a **`const`** *rvalue reference*. You are marking with `std::move()` a `const` object.

Marking a `const` object with `std::move()` for moving has no effect when it comes to move semantics because you can't move from a `const` object (i.e., you need to alter the moved-from object, but it is `const`-qualified).

An rvalue reference doesn't bind to a `const` object, but a `const` lvalue reference does. As a result, the `push_back(const A&)` overload is selected instead of the `push_back(A&&)` one, and therefore the `A` object is copy constructed.

---

#### Solution

Use a non-`const` rvalue reference instead:

```
void AddData(A&& a) // <-- non-const reference
{
    aList.push_back(std::move(a)); // selects push_back(A&&)
}
```

Comment: "Marking a const object with std::move() for moving has no effect " Technically, `std::move` just casts to an Rvalue, leaving you with a valid `const&&`.  It's merely that `std::string` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `const&&`, and so falls back on `const&`.  One could theoretically make a class with a `const&&` constructor.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, you are right `std::move()` has **always** the effect of performing a cast. However, the point I would like to make is that `std::move()` has no effect on a `const` object regarding *move semantics* because I think a `const` *rvalue reference* parameter function (e.g., of type `const A&&`) has no defined semantics. I hope it's more or less clear why the overload `vector<A>::push_back(const A&)` was being selected – there is no `vector<A>::push_back(const A&&)` overload after all.

Comment: Your answer is great as is. I'm just overly pedantic. a `const` rvalue reference parameter function has no defined semantics _for `std::string`_ or any other standard C++ type, but one is free to define their own semantics for `const&&` for their own classes.